# Add column To select Table by select all items from another table in sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Add column To select Table by select all items from another table in sql Server.
I have Tow Table Like this:

Table1

```
ID        ||         Title
1         ||         Ruler
2         ||         Book
3         ||         Pen
.         ||         .
.         ||         .
.         ||         .
```

Table2

```
itemID    ||         Price     ||         Date
1         ||         200       ||         2016-01-21
2         ||         30        ||         2017-03-01
3         ||         27        ||         2014-06-09
.         ||         .
.         ||         .
.         ||         .
```

Table Result

```
      Date         ||       Ruler      ||      Book       ||      pen         ||         … more 
2016-01-21         ||       200        ||                 ||                  ||         
2017-03-01         ||                  ||         30      ||                  ||         
2014-06-09         ||                  ||                 ||       27         ||         
.
.
.
```

It doesn't work

```
Declare @cols1 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)
Select @cols1 = stuff((select distinct ','+QuoteName([Title]) from table1 for xml path('')),1,1,'')
Set @Query = ' Select * from (


Select t2.[Date], t1.[Title], t2.Price from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1



on t2.ItemId = t1.Id ) a pivot (max([Price]) for [Title] in ( ' +@cols1 + ' ) ) p '
exec sp_executeSql @query
```

its return Max Price, but I Want Last Price Like this:

```
pivot (Select ([Price]) from table2 order by Date desc for [Title] in ( ' +@cols1 + ' ) ) p '
```

syntax Error return !?

Comment: Where did you get the syntax `Table1.ID.*`?   Try removing the `.*` from your current query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pivot as below:

```
Select * from (
   Select t2.[Date], t1.[Title], t2.Price from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1
   on t2.ItemId = t1.Id ) a
pivot (max([Price]) for [Title] in ([Ruler],[Book],[Pen]) ) p
```

For dynamic list of title's you can query as below:

```
Declare @cols1 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((select distinct ','+QuoteName([Title]) from table1 for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Set @Query = ' Select * from (
   Select t2.[Date], t1.[Title], t2.Price from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1
   on t2.ItemId = t1.Id ) a
pivot (max([Price]) for [Title] in ( ' +@cols1 + ' ) ) p '

exec sp_executeSql @query
```

Comment: `pivot (max([Price]) for [Title] in ( ' +@cols1 + ' ) ) p '`
its return Max Price, but I Want Last Price Like this:
`pivot (**Select ([Price]) from table2 order by Date desc** for [Title] in ( ' +@cols1 + ' ) ) p '`
syntax Error return !?

Comment: Can you please provide more input sample data?

Comment: oh my bad , your Answer is perfect. Thanks